# Localization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, webforms

I have a couple of tables with Spanish, Japan, French and other languages for my site. I don’t want to use Resource file cause it will take  a lot of time to  manually change. So I can take the current thread, take what culture you are using and if its lets say Italian to execute the query which retrieves the resource from the appropriate table. Is it possible to localization values from code behind instead of a resource files? A seperate resource file would mean we have to update (a lot of) translations in different locations (and with different tools) which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

We used database based approach similar to the one you described in a large ASP.NET web application with several supported languages.

In fact we did not change the Thread Culture, we had a login screen where the user could select the language and based on that selection we had an helper class which "knew" the current language and always retrieved to us values in that language.

as per changing values from code behind we had in all web forms (hundreds of them) a method called `initUITexts` which simply did something like the following:

```
label1.Text = LanguageHelper.GetText("PageName.label1.Text");
label2.Text = LanguageHelper.GetText("PageName.label2.Text");
button1.Text = LanguageHelper.GetText("PageName.button1.Text");
```

it is probably not the best or the only way but it worked fine for us and all logic of querying is encapsulated inside `LanguageHelper`.

Comment: So in onLoad of the form you just call the initUITexts method?

Comment: yepp that's what we do and in the markup controls only show the english text in square brakets so if we forgot to initialize in the initUITexts method we find it out while testing.